# MacBook Pro WiFi much slower than Ethernet and other devices

Tags: network, macos, wifi, airport, ethernet

I noticed that the WiFi speeds (ping & rates) on my MacBookPro11,3 (osx 10.12.6) are far, far worse than with Ethernet or with other devices on the same network.

With WiFi my speeds are rarely above 1 mbps; whereas over Ethernet (same machine, same router) or WiFi on my Android phone (S7) I get a steady 20-25 mbps.

I tried manually tweaking MTU to 1423; also setting DNS to Google 8.8.8.8; also tried deleting files from `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/` and rebooting. All to no avail.

Any way to diagnose this?

Comment: Specific MBP model?

Comment: @Allan it's a MacBookPro11,3

Answer (score 2):

WiFi by it's nature is generally going to be slower then most any wired network. Not only do you share the bandwidth with everything else attached to that WiFi access point, but you can also get slowed down by your relative position in relation to the antennas and what is between you and the antennas (Walls, steel, sheet-rock, whole buildings, etc.)

First it would be helpful to know what the make and model of the WiFi hardware is that you are connecting to, where you are in relation to the device and what is between you and the device.

Also you may want to try a different access point. Possibly at work, a friend's house, a local coffee shop or other public location with WiFi.

With WiFi there are a **lot** of variables and before you go looking into problems with your Mac (possible but less likely than other things) you need to see if the problem exists connecting to other access points or even if just moving closer to your current one solves it.

**Additionally** I would be tempted to look in both /Library/Preferences and ~/Library/Preferences for any network/WiFi related preference file. Delete them and reboot. Then set up your networks again: you *might* have a damaged prefs file.

Comment: Of course eth is better than wifi; but the issue seems obviously Mac related because other devices at the same physical location are getting 10x better speeds. There is nothing at all between my machine and the router other than several feet of air. The Android is at the same exact location.

Comment: Add this info to your original question not another comment, also info on WiFi equipment might be helpful. The more info you provide the better we are to help you. Also I point out Ethernet VS. WiFi as a suggestion: is the Mac too slow on ethernet also?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - it's also worth looking through the settings on the wifi base station / router - are there QoS rules being applied which throttle that MAC address (the NIC ID) and don't throttle the android device? Are the throttles in place for mobile devices as a whole versus desktops?

Comment: This is a reasonable suggestion. Issue *might* not be Mac related or *just* a problem with the Mac.